# How to escape from async Task

Tags: asynchronous, task, c#-5.0

I'm currently coding a little project for discord, and make use of the async functionality. But I'm having a little trouble understanding how to effectively escape my methods.

Say I have this method:

```
public async Task DoSomething(Item a, Person b)
{
   if(b is NPC)
   {
     await DoFunction()
   }

   // Code to Handle Everything else
}
```

My question is, how do I effectively leave the method after the first await? I'm told it's bad practice to use returns in async Tasks. Is it as simple as using effective Ifs and Elses, rather than singular ifs? This is whats puzzling me.

Comment: Who told you it is bad practice to use `return` in an async method? Just `return`, whoever told you that needs to have their head examined, or told you in some context that may not apply here.

Comment: Great. That's all I need to know. So I can simple return after the await? Like I would a normal method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best and easiest way is to simply return. Every method has to return sometime. I have no clue why and how it could be bad practice.

Answer (score 1):

I would try this:

```
        if (b is NPC)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                return DoFunction();
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Return of what? Return of DoSomething() or return of DoFunction()? Since DoSomething() is "async Task" you have no choice - you cannot return any value. In other words, this is not a bad practice, it will not even compile. If you remove "async" then DoSomething() would have to return Task, and then obviously it would not be able to call "await". Keep in mind that "async" changes the syntax of return value of a method

Comment: Return might be a bad term. I don't won't to return anything, I simply want it to stop executing the method after the await, if the first `if` expression is true.

Comment: if(b is NPC) is true then the code executes DoFunction() which always has to return Task or Task<T>.  If the task has not completed yet then your code will simply return from DoSomething(). Once the task completes it starts executing the next line after DoFunction() and the best way is just to call return inside if(b is NPC) {await DoFunction(); ....; return;}